# Mounting NTFS partition at boot with NTFS-3G and making it show up (and be accesible) in user interfaces (Files, Nemo, etc)

Tags: permissions, automount, fstab, ntfs-3g

I have a NTFS partition (without Windows having ever been installed in it) that I want to mount automatically after boot - but specifically using NTFS-3G so `chown` and `chmod` can be used on its folders.

Here is what I added to my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=[partition-uuid] /mnt/mydisk ntfs-3g auto,permissions,x-gvfs-show 0 1
```

Now, when I boot, the partition is indeed automatically mounted and the root can change ownership and permissions of folders in the NTFS partition - just as I wanted. Thanks to the `x-gvfs-show` option, the partition also shows up in software like Files and Nemo.

However, when I click on it in Files or Nemo, I get an error message with title "Unable to mount" that says:

> operation permitted for root only

If I then open Files or Nemo elevated as root, then when I click on the partition, I get the error message again with title "Unable to mount" but now saying:

> Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened. The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

In case I include the option `user` in my `/etc/fstab` mounting, i.e.:

```
UUID=[partition-uuid] /mnt/mydisk ntfs-3g auto,user,permissions,x-gvfs-show 0 1
```

Then, regardless of opening Files or Nemo as root or not, when I click on the partition, I get the error message with title "Unable to mount" and saying:

> Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened. The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

How could I have it such that my NTFS partition is automatically mounted using NTFS-3G and be accessible via user interface software like Files and Nemo?